# From json with Image URL to Base64 (date uri)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried to find this solution on the stackoverflow and had no success. I would like to get Base64 from my json file with image url. 
Example:

```
result({"image":"https://www.google.co.uk/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_120x44dp.png"});
```

Is there any suggestion how to get Base64 DataURI from it with Javascript or jQuery and avoid CORS errors?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Is there a url you want to encode in Base64? Can you add your expected output based on that example?

Comment: From url to data:image/png;base64....

Answer (score 0):

The right solution would be:

```
getBase64FromUrl("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4a/Logo_2013_Google.png");
function getBase64FromUrl(url) {
var img = new Image();
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
img.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width =this.width;
    canvas.height =this.height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    var url= dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");
};
img.src = url;
}
```

Make sure the server you are getting images from has got this header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"